# Why does RunThis() not do anything?

Tags: c#, ienumerator

I am working on a project in Unity3d and I was writing some code and initially I had the IEnumerator as Start instead of RunThis and the code ran fine, now I went to move it in to a new method and it didn't do anything. Could Someone explain this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class UniDLC : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start() {
        RunThis();
    }
    IEnumerator RunThis()
    {
        Debug.Log("ran");
        string url = "file://C:\\Users\\tom\\Documents\\test.txt";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }
}
```

P.s. I anticipate at least someone telling me about unityanswers, yes I know it exists but the site bugs out too much and I am sure someone hear can answer this, thank you.

Comment: Do something with the result of `RunThis` ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't try to actually use the *IEnumerator* returned by RunThis(), the compiler will not invoke the enumerator, so your code will not be called.

Since you are only returning one enumerated object,

```
RunThis().MoveNext();
```

should show the enumerator working.